# Should the temperature spikes with my new 2020 MacBook Pro be a concern?

Tags: cpu, temperature, xcode, android-studio

[mac overview and temperature readings from opening xcode/android studio/launching app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KrPl4.jpg)

It only spikes for a short time when opening programs, is that okay? I'm using Intel Power Gadget to read the temp.

When I had pod install running (for cloud_firestore?) the user cpu spiked for a few minutes, with the fans going... after that I went to geek squad, they told me to watch the temp... I'm not sure how else to stress test it.

[cpu load from running pods](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gL48d.jpg)

I have 18 more days to return/exchange.

EDIT

Decided to keep it. Got the CPU to stop spiking when running Xcode build by going to Product>Scheme>Edit Scheme and then uncheck Find Implicit Dependencies.

I also stopped Spotlight in activity monitor when running a simulator, it hogs a lot of CPU.

When I started using Visual Studio Code, Code Helper Render hogged a lot of CPU, my fans were going for an hour before I stopped Code Helper Render in activity monitor. Before stopping it I ran some commands in terminal... can't remember exactly but something along the lines of `ps aux | grep photo` I believe and I tried something with `add .` sorry I don't remember and I can't find the page I got it from. (Warning I had my iPad running via SideCar and the screen went pixelated, unplugged it and it was fine...)

Comment: I don't know the MacBook, but temperatures of 100 degrees are worrying and abnormal. I would say to return (or exchange if you keep the right to return).

Comment: There's the Apple community [Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/340994/) - I'd delete the question here and ask there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When i am answering this question you have 3 days remaining. If **you** feel as though it seems an issue than maybe ask for an exchange. However the Apple laptops run hot because they have powerful CPUs which generate a lot of heat and those CPUs are in an extremely thin laptop so heat builds up quickly.   This is perfectly normal.  The laptop will shutdown if the CPUs get to a critical temperature so if this is not happening, then just enjoy your laptop.  I've rarely seen a computer shutdown to due overheating.

Hope this helps -NMD

Answer (score 0):

With newer MacBook Pros, this is, sadly, normal. The devices build by Apple lack sufficient cooling capacity for their increasingly strong processors under full load, all in the name of making them more thin and "sleek looking". There have been countless videos and articles documenting these issues in the last few years.

Is it good design? Absolutely not. CPUs reaching more than 90 °C regularly is going to shorten their lifespan significantly.

Will this matter? Probably not. CPUs can withstand quite a lot, and usually they will last a few years even with this abuse. So if you don't want to stick with your current MacBook forever, you probably won't experience any problems. The only problem that's noticable during regular operation is that the CPU will thermal throttle a lot when used for high-performance tasks over a prolonged amount of time, thus getting extremely slow. But if you only use it for programming, you won't notice, as programming mostly consists of short "bursts" of high performance compiling with long periods of cooling down.

I personally wouldn't buy a MacBook Pro (this being one of the reasons, next to abysmal repairability and outrageous pricing), but that's just my opinion.